# Unable to disable cookies by setting cookieAcceptPolicy to .never

Tags: swift

I use `HTTPCookieStorage` class to insert my own `HTTPCookie`. I noticed that if I set `cookieAcceptPolicy` to `.never` then cookies still writes to storage. Why?

```
let someCookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [
    .name: "cookie",
    .value: "value",
    .path: "/",
    .domain: "domain.com",
    .expires: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60)
])!

let storage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
storage.cookieAcceptPolicy = .never
print(storage.cookies?.count) // 0
storage.setCookie(someCookie)
print(storage.cookies?.count) // 1
```

As you can see `setCookie` works even if I set `cookieAcceptPolicy` to `.never`

Comment: cookie expiration also behaves strangely.